# Excel VBA macro. How to write an absolute cell reference into a cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with an index as the first sheet. Each subsequent sheet is a dive-log. As I am one of many using this workbook, it needs to be as 'automatic' as possible (because people are lazy)...

Each log has a macro button for 'New Dive'. The macro creates a new sheet, names it with the new sheet number (the dive number) and clears relevant data ready for filling in. Currently the index sheet needs to be filled manually, but it's being ignored.

I have the macro close, but it's the last step that has me stumped. I've tried `Activecell.FormulaR1C1 and Cells(r,c) =...` gets close, but no piece of pie. I'm also VERY new at this.

Here's my code

```
Sub Add_links()
'
' Add_links Macro
' Adds links to the index sheet so it 'fills itself in'... 

' Each dive is on the row 9 more than the dive number (bear in mind each log is 50 higher than the previous)

Dim Divenumber As Double
Dim Rownumber As Double

Range("I7").Select: Divenumber = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1

' Make Linenumber the same as Divenumber.
' Do a loop of reducing the Linenumber by 50 until it's in the range 1 to 50.
' Add 9 to that and it becomes the row number of the index sheet

Rownumber = Divenumber

Do
Rownumber = Rownumber - 50
Loop While Rownumber > 50

Rownumber = Rownumber + 9

Worksheets("Dive Index").Activate

Range("A" & Rownumber).Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'Dive " & Divenumber & "'!A1"
'Project number (in cell F4)
Range("B" & Rownumber).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Dive " & Divenumber & "'!F4"
'Task(in cell C7)
Range("C" & Rownumber & ":G" & Rownumber).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Dive " & Divenumber & "'!C7"
'Start date (in cell C21)
Range("H" & Rownumber).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Dive " & Divenumber & Chr(39) & "!$C$21"
'Start time (in cell E21)
Range("I" & Rownumber).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Dive " & Divenumber & Chr(39) & "!$E$21"
'End date (in cell F21)
Range("J" & Rownumber & ":K" & Rownumber).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Dive " & Divenumber & Chr(39) & "!$F$21"
'End time (in cell G21)
Range("L" & Rownumber).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Dive " & Divenumber & Chr(39) & "!$G$21"

Sheets("Dive " & Divenumber).Select
Range("A23").Select
End Sub
```

This one gets me the closest..

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Dive " & Divenumber & "'!F4"
```

but adds a couple of unwanted ' to the cell.. Looks like this...

`='Dive 53'!'F4'` (should be `='Dive 53'!F4`)

Comment: Use `Formula` not `FormulaR1C1` since you aren't using `R1C1` referencing.

Comment: And use `Range("H" & Rownumber).Formula ...`rather than Select and ActiveCell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach avoids using hyperlinks (which I find hard to maintain) and instead uses the `BeforeDoubleClick` event of the index sheet to provide equivalent functionality.

This code goes into the code module for the Dive Index worksheet, so that it picks up the double-click event on the index:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    '// This function is called whenever the sheet is double-clicked
    '// It checks the value of the target (selected) cell, to see if it is a reference
    '// to a dive sheet. If so, it activates that sheet

    '// Get hold of the contents of the target cell
    Dim sTarget As String: sTarget = Target.Cells(1, 1).Value

    '// Check if it refers to a dive sheet
    If Left(sTarget, 5) = "Dive " Then
        Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
        On Error Resume Next
            '// Try to find the worksheet referred to by the target cell
            Set wsTarget = Worksheets(sTarget)
        On Error GoTo 0

        '// Check that a target sheet was found
        If wsTarget Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        '// Activate the sheet
        wsTarget.Activate

        '// Cancel the default action for double-click
        Cancel = True

    End If


End Sub
```

This is the code for your function Add_Links(). I am not sure how you invoke it, but it works effectively the same as your example, except I have used some simpler techniques.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_links()

        '
        ' Add_links Macro
        ' Adds links to the index sheet so it 'fills itself in'...

        ' Each dive is on the row 9 more than the dive number (bear in mind each log is 50 higher than the previous)

        Dim Divenumber As Double
        Dim Rownumber As Double


        Dim wsDive As Worksheet
        Set wsDive = ActiveSheet

        '// Dive number is in cell I7 of the sheet
        Divenumber = wsDive.Range("I7").Value

        '// Make sure the sheet name corresponds to the dive number
        Dim sDiveName As String
        sDiveName = "Dive " & Divenumber
        wsDive.Name = sDiveName


        '// Calculate the row number for the index entry
        '-- -- Rownumber = Divenumber Mod 50 + 9
        '// Use below if dive numbers in sheet run from 1 to 50, not 0 to 49
        Rownumber = (Divenumber - 1) Mod 50 + 10

        '// Get a reference to the index sheet
        Dim wsIndex As Worksheet: Set wsIndex = Worksheets("Dive Index")

        '// Get a reference to column A in the index entry row
        Dim rLink As Range: Set rLink = wsIndex.Range("A" & Rownumber)

        '// Put the Dive name into column A
        rLink.Value = sDiveName



        '// Reference data from the dive sheet into the index sheet ================

        '// Project number (in cell F4)
        rLink.Offset(0, 1).Formula = ReferenceToCell(wsDive.Range("F4")) '// Index Column B

        '// Task(in cell C7)
        rLink.Offset(0, 2).Formula = ReferenceToCell(wsDive.Range("C7")) '// Index Column C

        '// Start date (in cell C21)
        rLink.Offset(0, 7).Formula = ReferenceToCell(wsDive.Range("C21")) '// Index Column H

        '// Start time (in cell E21)
        rLink.Offset(0, 8).Formula = ReferenceToCell(wsDive.Range("E21")) '// Index Column I

        '// End date (in cell F21)
        rLink.Offset(0, 9).Formula = ReferenceToCell(wsDive.Range("F21")) '// Index Column J

        '// End time (in cell G21)
        rLink.Offset(0, 11).Formula = ReferenceToCell(wsDive.Range("G21")) '// Index Column L


End Sub

Private Function ReferenceToCell(rCell As Range) As String
    '// This function returns a formula that references the value of the given cell
    ReferenceToCell = "='" & rCell.Parent.Name & "'!" & rCell.Cells(1, 1).Address

End Function
```

Comment: I noticed that the calculation of the row number needs slight modification if the dive numbers in a workbook run from, for example 1-50, 51-100 etc. The calculation `Rownumber = Divenumber Mod 50 + 9` has the effect that the last dive in the workbook i.e. Dive 50, Dive 100 etc go into row 9 instead of row 59. To fix this, the code should be `Rownumber = (DiveNumber - 1) Mod 50 + 10`